# How to get list of all the procedure inside a package oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, data-dictionary

Can I get the name of all the function inside a package.
Suppose I have a package PKG_OWA and I want to list all the procedure inside the package.

Comment: inside the package body or in the specification?

Comment: I want the list of body only.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The data dictionary view ALL_PROCEDURES (or USER_PROCEDURES if you just want your packages).    [Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2025.htm#i1585339)

```
 select procedure_name
 from all_procedures
 where owner = 'YOU'
 and object_name = 'YOUR_PACKAGE'
```

---

This lists the public procedures exposed in the package specification.  There is no easy way of retrieving the private procedures (that is, those specified only in the package body) except by processing the source text. Oracle do provide a utility PL/SCOPE which we can use to gather this information, but it requires us to change session settings and recompile our code, so it may not be suitable in all situations. [Find out more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44026333/146325).

Answer (score 13):

I use this one:

your package:

```
SELECT *
FROM ALL_OBJECTS
WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'PACKAGE' 
    and owner = 'owner_name'
    and object_name = 'package_name'
```

your procedures (only from specs, i.e. global):

```
select *
 from all_procedures
 where owner = 'owner_name'
 and object_name = 'package_name'
```

and in/out arguments from procedure:

```
select * 
from ALL_ARGUMENTS 
where owner = 'owner_name'
    and package_name = 'package_name'
    and object_name = 'procedure_name'
```

enjoy!

Comment: Upvated. Thank you very much for the ALL_ARGUMENTS reference.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe useful to someone, this is a way to find out procedure and function specified on package body only too.

```
select name, 
       type,
       decode(usage,'DECLARATION', 'body only', 'DEFINITION', 'spec and body', usage) defined_on,
       line body_line
  from user_identifiers ui
  where type in ('PROCEDURE', 'FUNCTION')
  and usage_context_id = (select usage_id
    from user_identifiers
      where object_name = ui.object_name
        and object_type = ui.object_type
        and usage_context_id = 0)
  and object_name = 'your package name'
  and object_type = 'PACKAGE BODY'
  order by name
```

Comment: This is the right answer! Tested OK on 12c but the view USER_IDENTIFIERS exists since at least 11g.

Comment: By default this view is empty. It is populated by PL/SCOPE, which requires us to recompile our code with special settings. [Find out more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44026333/146325)

Answer (score 6):

The answer from APC is on the correct lines but the SQL given will only list the procedures owned by 'YOU' and is the same as selecting from USER_PROCEDURES but there could be packages in other schema

```
SQL> select * from all_procedures where owner='TEST';

OWNER                          OBJECT_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
PROCEDURE_NAME                 AGG PIP IMPLTYPEOWNER
------------------------------ --- --- ------------------------------
IMPLTYPENAME                   PAR INT DET AUTHID
------------------------------ --- --- --- ------------
TEST                           TEST
                               NO  NO
                               NO  NO  NO  DEFINER

SQL> select * from user_procedures;

OBJECT_NAME                    PROCEDURE_NAME                 AGG PIP
------------------------------ ------------------------------ --- ---
IMPLTYPEOWNER                  IMPLTYPENAME                   PAR INT DET
 ------------------------------ ------------------------------ --- --- ---
AUTHID
------------
TEST                                                          NO  NO
                                                          NO  NO  NO
```

Also note that when you grant and revoke execute on a package, procedure or function, these show up in the DBA_TAB_PRIVS table (same table as insert/update/delete privileges on tables)

Once you avhe the name of a packages such as the Oracle supplied DBMS ones ,you can also use DESC which will provide a list of the parameters and types expected e.g.

```
SQL> desc dbms_lob
PROCEDURE APPEND
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 DEST_LOB                       BLOB                    IN/OUT
 SRC_LOB                        BLOB                    IN
PROCEDURE APPEND
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 DEST_LOB                       CLOB                    IN/OUT
 SRC_LOB                        CLOB                    IN
PROCEDURE CLOSE
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        BLOB                    IN/OUT
PROCEDURE CLOSE
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        CLOB                    IN/OUT
PROCEDURE CLOSE
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 FILE_LOC                       BINARY FILE LOB         IN/OUT
FUNCTION COMPARE RETURNS NUMBER(38)
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_1                          BLOB                    IN
 LOB_2                          BLOB                    IN
 AMOUNT                         NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
 OFFSET_1                       NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
 OFFSET_2                       NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
FUNCTION COMPARE RETURNS NUMBER(38)
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_1                          CLOB                    IN
 LOB_2                          CLOB                    IN
 AMOUNT                         NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
 OFFSET_1                       NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
 OFFSET_2                       NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
FUNCTION COMPARE RETURNS NUMBER(38)
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 FILE_1                         BINARY FILE LOB         IN
 FILE_2                         BINARY FILE LOB         IN
 AMOUNT                         NUMBER(38)              IN
 OFFSET_1                       NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
 OFFSET_2                       NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
PROCEDURE CONVERTTOBLOB
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 DEST_LOB                       BLOB                    IN/OUT
 SRC_CLOB                       CLOB                    IN
 AMOUNT                         NUMBER(38)              IN
 DEST_OFFSET                    NUMBER(38)              IN/OUT
 SRC_OFFSET                     NUMBER(38)              IN/OUT
 BLOB_CSID                      NUMBER                  IN
 LANG_CONTEXT                   NUMBER(38)              IN/OUT
 WARNING                        NUMBER(38)              OUT
PROCEDURE CONVERTTOCLOB
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 DEST_LOB                       CLOB                    IN/OUT
 SRC_BLOB                       BLOB                    IN
 AMOUNT                         NUMBER(38)              IN
 DEST_OFFSET                    NUMBER(38)              IN/OUT
 SRC_OFFSET                     NUMBER(38)              IN/OUT
 BLOB_CSID                      NUMBER                  IN
 LANG_CONTEXT                   NUMBER(38)              IN/OUT
 WARNING                        NUMBER(38)              OUT
PROCEDURE COPY
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 DEST_LOB                       BLOB                    IN/OUT
 SRC_LOB                        BLOB                    IN
 AMOUNT                         NUMBER(38)              IN
 DEST_OFFSET                    NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
 SRC_OFFSET                     NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
PROCEDURE COPY
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 DEST_LOB                       CLOB                    IN/OUT
 SRC_LOB                        CLOB                    IN
 AMOUNT                         NUMBER(38)              IN
 DEST_OFFSET                    NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
 SRC_OFFSET                     NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
PROCEDURE CREATETEMPORARY
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        BLOB                    IN/OUT
 CACHE                          BOOLEAN                 IN
 DUR                            BINARY_INTEGER          IN     DEFAULT
PROCEDURE CREATETEMPORARY
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        CLOB                    IN/OUT
 CACHE                          BOOLEAN                 IN
 DUR                            BINARY_INTEGER          IN     DEFAULT
PROCEDURE ERASE
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        BLOB                    IN/OUT
 AMOUNT                         NUMBER(38)              IN/OUT
 OFFSET                         NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
PROCEDURE ERASE
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        CLOB                    IN/OUT
 AMOUNT                         NUMBER(38)              IN/OUT
 OFFSET                         NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
PROCEDURE FILECLOSE
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 FILE_LOC                       BINARY FILE LOB         IN/OUT
PROCEDURE FILECLOSEALL
FUNCTION FILEEXISTS RETURNS NUMBER(38)
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 FILE_LOC                       BINARY FILE LOB         IN
PROCEDURE FILEGETNAME
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 FILE_LOC                       BINARY FILE LOB         IN
 DIR_ALIAS                      VARCHAR2                OUT
 FILENAME                       VARCHAR2                OUT
FUNCTION FILEISOPEN RETURNS NUMBER(38)
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 FILE_LOC                       BINARY FILE LOB         IN
PROCEDURE FILEOPEN
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 FILE_LOC                       BINARY FILE LOB         IN/OUT
 OPEN_MODE                      BINARY_INTEGER          IN     DEFAULT
PROCEDURE FREETEMPORARY
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        BLOB                    IN/OUT
PROCEDURE FREETEMPORARY
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        CLOB                    IN/OUT
FUNCTION GETCHUNKSIZE RETURNS NUMBER(38)
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        BLOB                    IN
FUNCTION GETCHUNKSIZE RETURNS NUMBER(38)
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        CLOB                    IN
FUNCTION GETLENGTH RETURNS NUMBER(38)
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        BLOB                    IN
FUNCTION GETLENGTH RETURNS NUMBER(38)
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        CLOB                    IN
FUNCTION GETLENGTH RETURNS NUMBER(38)
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 FILE_LOC                       BINARY FILE LOB         IN
FUNCTION GET_STORAGE_LIMIT RETURNS NUMBER(38)
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        CLOB                    IN
FUNCTION GET_STORAGE_LIMIT RETURNS NUMBER(38)
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        BLOB                    IN
FUNCTION INSTR RETURNS NUMBER(38)
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        BLOB                    IN
 PATTERN                        RAW                     IN
 OFFSET                         NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
 NTH                            NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
FUNCTION INSTR RETURNS NUMBER(38)
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        CLOB                    IN
 PATTERN                        VARCHAR2                IN
 OFFSET                         NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
 NTH                            NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
FUNCTION INSTR RETURNS NUMBER(38)
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 FILE_LOC                       BINARY FILE LOB         IN
 PATTERN                        RAW                     IN
 OFFSET                         NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
 NTH                            NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
FUNCTION ISOPEN RETURNS NUMBER(38)
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        BLOB                    IN
FUNCTION ISOPEN RETURNS NUMBER(38)
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        CLOB                    IN
FUNCTION ISOPEN RETURNS NUMBER(38)
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 FILE_LOC                       BINARY FILE LOB         IN
FUNCTION ISTEMPORARY RETURNS NUMBER(38)
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        BLOB                    IN
FUNCTION ISTEMPORARY RETURNS NUMBER(38)
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        CLOB                    IN
PROCEDURE LOADBLOBFROMFILE
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 DEST_LOB                       BLOB                    IN/OUT
 SRC_BFILE                      BINARY FILE LOB         IN
 AMOUNT                         NUMBER(38)              IN
 DEST_OFFSET                    NUMBER(38)              IN/OUT
 SRC_OFFSET                     NUMBER(38)              IN/OUT
PROCEDURE LOADCLOBFROMFILE
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 DEST_LOB                       CLOB                    IN/OUT
 SRC_BFILE                      BINARY FILE LOB         IN
 AMOUNT                         NUMBER(38)              IN
 DEST_OFFSET                    NUMBER(38)              IN/OUT
 SRC_OFFSET                     NUMBER(38)              IN/OUT
 BFILE_CSID                     NUMBER                  IN
 LANG_CONTEXT                   NUMBER(38)              IN/OUT
 WARNING                        NUMBER(38)              OUT
PROCEDURE LOADFROMFILE
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 DEST_LOB                       BLOB                    IN/OUT
 SRC_LOB                        BINARY FILE LOB         IN
 AMOUNT                         NUMBER(38)              IN
 DEST_OFFSET                    NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
 SRC_OFFSET                     NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
PROCEDURE LOADFROMFILE
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 DEST_LOB                       CLOB                    IN/OUT
 SRC_LOB                        BINARY FILE LOB         IN
 AMOUNT                         NUMBER(38)              IN
 DEST_OFFSET                    NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
 SRC_OFFSET                     NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
PROCEDURE OPEN
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        BLOB                    IN/OUT
 OPEN_MODE                      BINARY_INTEGER          IN
PROCEDURE OPEN
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        CLOB                    IN/OUT
 OPEN_MODE                      BINARY_INTEGER          IN
PROCEDURE OPEN
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 FILE_LOC                       BINARY FILE LOB         IN/OUT
 OPEN_MODE                      BINARY_INTEGER          IN     DEFAULT
PROCEDURE READ
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        BLOB                    IN
 AMOUNT                         NUMBER(38)              IN/OUT
 OFFSET                         NUMBER(38)              IN
 BUFFER                         RAW                     OUT
PROCEDURE READ
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        CLOB                    IN
 AMOUNT                         NUMBER(38)              IN/OUT
 OFFSET                         NUMBER(38)              IN
 BUFFER                         VARCHAR2                OUT
PROCEDURE READ
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 FILE_LOC                       BINARY FILE LOB         IN
 AMOUNT                         NUMBER(38)              IN/OUT
 OFFSET                         NUMBER(38)              IN
 BUFFER                         RAW                     OUT
FUNCTION SUBSTR RETURNS RAW
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        BLOB                    IN
 AMOUNT                         NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
 OFFSET                         NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
FUNCTION SUBSTR RETURNS VARCHAR2
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        CLOB                    IN
 AMOUNT                         NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
 OFFSET                         NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
FUNCTION SUBSTR RETURNS RAW
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 FILE_LOC                       BINARY FILE LOB         IN
 AMOUNT                         NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
 OFFSET                         NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
PROCEDURE TRIM
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        BLOB                    IN/OUT
 NEWLEN                         NUMBER(38)              IN
PROCEDURE TRIM
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        CLOB                    IN/OUT
 NEWLEN                         NUMBER(38)              IN
PROCEDURE WRITE
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        BLOB                    IN/OUT
 AMOUNT                         NUMBER(38)              IN
 OFFSET                         NUMBER(38)              IN
 BUFFER                         RAW                     IN
PROCEDURE WRITE
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        CLOB                    IN/OUT
 AMOUNT                         NUMBER(38)              IN
 OFFSET                         NUMBER(38)              IN
 BUFFER                         VARCHAR2                IN
PROCEDURE WRITEAPPEND
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        BLOB                    IN/OUT
 AMOUNT                         NUMBER(38)              IN
 BUFFER                         RAW                     IN
PROCEDURE WRITEAPPEND
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LOB_LOC                        CLOB                    IN/OUT
 AMOUNT                         NUMBER(38)              IN
 BUFFER                         VARCHAR2                IN
```