# Retreive a list of private procedures/functions from a package body

Tags: oracle, package

I want to obtain a list with all private procedures/functions from a package body.

For public object it is easy but I have no idea how to do that for private objects.

Answer (score 4):

The nature of private functions is that they are private. There are no data dictionary views which expose them by default.  USER_PROCEDURES and  USER_ARGUMENTS only show information for public procedures (the ones defined in a package spec0.

However, we can get information about them using PL/SCOPE, but doing so requires a little bit of additional effort:

1. `SQL>  alter session set plscope_settings='IDENTIFIERS:ALL';`
2. `SQL>  alter package your_package compile body;`

Now you can find your private program units with this query:

```
select ui.type, ui.name, ui.usage_id
from user_identifiers ui
where ui.object_name = 'YOUR_PACKAGE'
and ui.usage = 'DEFINITION'
and ui.type in ('PROCEDURE', 'FUNCTION')
minus
( select 'PROCEDURE', upr.procedure_name 
  from user_procedures upr
  where upr.object_name = 'YOUR_PACKAGE'
  union
  select 'FUNCTION', uarg.object_name
  from user_arguments uarg
  where uarg.package_name = 'YOUR_PACKAGE'
  and uarg.position = 0 
);
```

To get the arguments of a private procedure plug the USAGE_ID from the previous query into this query:

```
select ui.name
       , ui.type
       , ui.usage_id
       , ui2.type as param_datatype
from user_identifiers ui
     left join user_identifiers ui2
        on ui2.usage_context_id = ui.usage_id 
where ui.object_name = 'YOUR_PACKAGE'
and ui.usage = 'DECLARATION'
and ui.usage_context_id = :private_proc_usage_id
/
```

This needs to be a left join because `user_identifiers` has datatype entries for scalar datatypes (character, number, date, clob) but not complex datatypes (xmltype, user-defined types).

We can get lots of information about procedures from PL/SCOPE, even though it is not as easy as querying USER_PROCEDURES  or USER_ARGUMENTS (in fact, it is surprisingly clunky).  [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_plscope.htm#BABJCFGC). Be aware that PL/SCOPE data is stored on the SYSAUX tablespace, so don't get into hot water with your DBA!